# How To Remove Noobslab/Themes?

Tags: apt, themes

I tried installing a theme using the following lines:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vimix-flat-themes
```

Needless to say the theme did not install as expected and I would like to remove what was installed. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Here is the source web page i followed:

http://sourcedigit.com/9432-top-10-best-custom-themes-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: Use the third answer (`ppa-purge`).

Answer (score 3):

To remove the theme and the PPA -

`sudo apt-get purge vimix-flat-themes`

`sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:noobslab/themes`